# Navigating to a specific tab bar - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to simulate a scenario when a button in the extra view Controller is clicked (Second View Controller --> Extra UIViewController ), it returns the tab bar controller with with the second view controller ( with tab bar item title 2) as the display page and not the first view controller. The default tabbed application is used for my reference.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAg8Z.png) is the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are asking how to implement a back button in Cocoa Touch.

Back buttons do not actually act in the view controller where they were tabbed. View controllers are normally pushed onto a stack of view controllers where the top of the stack is the visible one. If the user now tabs the back button this action will be performed by the view controller below the top of the stack, that just pops the last controller off which means you are back.
To do this, you normally define the last view controller as your delegate and then use that to send messages to it.

I hope I interpreted your question correctly. If not, could you please elaborate?

Comment: its not the back button. When i press the button I'm suppose to see the secondViewController and not the firstViewController , even tho its the first item on the tab bar.